# Fatal error: при вызове функции convertDateBackwards()

Tags: php

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество помогите понять в чем ошибка.

```
 function date2db($date, $symb = '.') {
    $tmp = explode($symb,$date);
    if (count($tmp) == 3)
        return $return = $tmp[2].'.'.$tmp[1].'.'.$tmp[0];
    else 
        return $date;
}

function date2db2($date) {
    return str_replace("-",".",$date);
}

function convertDate($content) {
    $pattern = "/(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d\d\d)/i";
    $replacement = "$3.$2.$1";
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
}

function convertDateBackwards($content) {
    $pattern = "/(\d\d\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)/i";
    $replacement = "$3.$2.$1";
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
}

ob_start();
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Feb 1998 13:24:18 GMT"); 
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0,pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"WINDOWS-1251\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
echo "<SECURITY>";    
echo "<MAIN>";
    echo "<ROWSET>";
        echo "<ROW>";
            echo "<CODE>somecode</CODE>";
            echo "<DESC>somedesc</DESC>";
            echo "<NOMINAL>somenominal</NOMINAL>";
            echo "<DATE>2012.01.01</DATE>";
            echo "<TYPE>sometype</TYPE>";
        echo "</ROW>";
    echo "</ROWSET>";
echo "</MAIN>";
echo "</SECURITY>";

$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
$c=oci_connect("test", "test", "testdb");

$rclob = oci_new_descriptor($c, OCI_D_LOB);
$clob = oci_new_descriptor($c, OCI_D_LOB);

$s = oci_parse($c, "begin :ret:=some_pcg.get_xml_data(:data, :out); end;");

oci_bind_by_name($s, ":ret", $rclob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":data", $clob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);

oci_bind_by_name($s, ":out", $out, 1000);

$clob->writeTemporary($content);
$r = oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT); // use OCI_DEFAULT so $lob->save() works
//$e = oci_error($s);
//var_dump($e);
oci_commit($c);
echo $out;

$returnvalues = convertDateBackwards($rclob->load()); // !!!!ВОТ НА ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ ОШИБКА!!!!
$returnvalues = str_replace("<SECURITY>","<SECURITY ret=\"".$out."\">",$returnvalues);

echo convertDateBackwards($rclob->load());

echo $returnvalues;
$clob->free(); 
$rclob->free(); 
oci_free_statement($s);
oci_close($c);
```

Ошибка вылетает такая:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
> function convertDateBackwards() in
> C:\webserver\[www.site.ru](http://www.site.ru)\www\blocks\create_xml.php
> on line

Comment: Вы уверены, что вы подключаете файл, содержащий функцию к create_xml.php?

Comment: @knes не совсем понял вопрос!

Comment: Как выглядит указанная строка в указанном файле?
В каком файле лежит функция convertDateBackwards?
Он подключен явно к файлу, в котором происходит ошибка?

Comment: всё в одном файле, добавил в описание все содержимое файла. Я еще [здесь][1] ошибки обсуждал. Warning удалось исправить, а вот Fatal error: никак не могу победить [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/154068/php-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-xml-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4-oracle-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function

Comment: Думаю очевидно, что проблема именно в определении(описании) функции. По какой-то причине интерпритартор не может его найти.

Comment: Ну вот же функция описана, выше по коду, в самом начале:
<pre><code>
function convertDateBackwards($content) {
    $pattern = "/(\d\d\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)/i";
    $replacement = "$3.$2.$1";
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
}
</code></pre>

Comment: Просто копия вопроса http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011113/fatal-error-when-calling-the-function-convertdatebackwardsДаже комментарии совпадают...) Где Вы этот код вообще взяли? Вывести текст в буфер, забрать его из буфера в переменную, очистить буфер, потом за каким-то хреном изменить формат даты, которую чуть выше вывели... Все, цензурные комментарии кончились...

Comment: @Равнодушный, там edit был меньше часа назад. Похоже что это один и тот же чел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Локально прогнал в таком виде(объявление ф-ции и вызов копировал из вопроса):

```
<?php
function convertDateBackwards($content) {
    $pattern = "/(\d\d\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)/i";
    $replacement = "$3.$2.$1";
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
}

print "\n".$returnvalues = convertDateBackwards('2102.55.11')."\n";
?>
```

Всё работает. Смотрите у себя.

Comment: Да спасибо, коллега! Увидел, что вы подставили даты, а мне совсем другой параметр приходит :), никак не дата, буду разбираться!!!

Comment: Не думаю что проблема в данных. Хотя конечно нужно весь код локально прогнать.

Comment: Погуглил, однозначно не в данных проблема. Входит строка возвращает то, что совпадает с патерном в этой строке. Надо глубже смотреть.